# Having problems with check (char a) statement (with an if operator)

Tags: if-statement

As you see i have a check method defined in the class definition. The problem is that i cant compare the two characters since it doesnt let me to define char e in the class defintion. How do i fix this task? `a==e` is written by me for reference of what i have been doing, but i get the error message:

> Syntax Error(s)
> **tester**.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
> if(a==e){
> ^
> symbol:   variable e
> location: class **tester**
> 1 error

Thankful for any help!

```
public static void check (char a){`
        `if(a==e){`
            `System.out.println("if");`
        `}else{`
            `System.out.println("else");
        }
    }
```